Validate the time a message was signed
How can I validate the block an off-chain signature was signed? Including the block hash in the signed data is not an option as it could be faked by a signature that was created at a later time. Having a smart wallet co-sign could be a solution maybe? Please keep in mind that I would like to keep the signature off-chain, with no state changes. Thank you already.
